# Why can't my I assign TextLength to a Long value type?

Tags: c#, winforms, type-conversion

```
public string Name;    
public long Patient_ID;    
patient.Name = Name.Text;    
patient.Patient_ID = Patient_ID.TextLength;
```

When i use **.Text** for string it isn't working but I don't know what to give for long datatype. If i give **.TextLength** only one digit is storing. I also tried **.Tostring()** but its not working. I need to store minimum 9 digits in Patient_ID? What should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're having is that Patient_ID is a **long** datatype and not a string. The following is an example of taking a long and getting it's length.

```
long Patient_ID = 200;
long x =  Patient_ID.ToString().Length;
```

Here is your code converted to use this.

```
public string Name;    
public long Patient_ID;    
patient.Name = Name.Text;    
patient.Patient_ID = Patient_ID.ToString().Length;
```

Comment: yea i am using Patient_ID as long datatype, because i want to make it as a primary key. but i couldn't do it

Answer (score 1):

i mean 9 digit id can be implemented in different ways  if this is just a regular id which you wont to use ase a unique identifier but will not use any calculation on it like adding number then you can use string and you probably will be fine but if you want to stare and manipulate big numbers you might use BigInteger

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268366.aspx

Comment: Thank you, i am not going to do any calculation but i want to generate as unique identifier to the Patient_ID... Can i generate if i use string datatype? BigInteger is not working in VS2008!!